systemd-remount-fs randomly fails with "mount: /: mount point is busy."
I recently switched to a read-only root filesystem using Yocto (Kirkstone version) and use the Yocto volatiles feature to keep some directories writable - for instance the entire /etc, /home, etc...
Yocto generates some systemd services for setting up the overlays. The upper directories for the overlays are in another writable partition mounted to /data
$ mount | grep overlay
overlay on /etc type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data/etc,workdir=/data/.etc-work)
overlay on /home type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/home,upperdir=/data/home,workdir=/data/.home-work)
overlay on /opt/config type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/opt/config,upperdir=/data/opt/config,workdir=/data/opt/.config-work)
overlay on /usr/share/app type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/usr/share/app,upperdir=/data/usr/share/app,workdir=/data/usr/share/.app-work)

However, in very rare cases, I observe that systemd-remount-fs.service fails at startup with the error "mount: /: mount point is busy". As a result the overlayfs are not mounted, since the Yocto-generated systemd services only operate with a read-only filesystem.
Here is the sequence of events for my root filesystem:

The root filesystem is first mounted as rw from the kernel command line.
I have an fstab entry to remount it as ro via systemd: /dev/root / auto ro 1 0

Questions: How could I make sure the systemd-remount-fs service never fail?
What do you think could lead to that "busy" issue?
To troubleshoot, I analyzed the systemd dependencies using systemctl and systemd-analyze to identify possible race conditions. However, I didn't find anything obvious. Below is the output of systemctl list-dependencies. Any suggestions are welcome!
Systemd version: 250
$ systemctl list-dependencies
[...]
● │ │ ├─local-fs.target
● │ │ │ ├─-.mount
○ │ │ │ ├─data-etc.service
○ │ │ │ ├─data-home.service
○ │ │ │ ├─data-opt-config.service
○ │ │ │ ├─data-usr-share-app.service
● │ │ │ ├─data.mount
× │ │ │ ├─systemd-remount-fs.service
● │ │ │ ├─tmp.mount
○ │ │ │ ├─var-volatile-cache.service
○ │ │ │ ├─var-volatile-lib.service
○ │ │ │ ├─var-volatile-spool.service
○ │ │ │ ├─var-volatile-srv.service
● │ │ │ └─var-volatile.mount
● │ │ └─swap.target
● │ └─timers.target
● │   └─systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
● ├─getty.target
● │ ├─getty@tty1.service
● │ └─serial-getty@ttyS0.service
● └─remote-fs.target

